# Getting Name of MS Teams Channel Message Attachment

Tags: attachments, flow, microsoft-teams

I'm trying to get the name of an attachment that was sent to my MS Team Channel's email. It was posted as a message on the conversation board, which is how I've been referencing it.

Right now, I have the message attachment as a Current Item in my dynamic content, but I can't figure out how to isolate just the attachment name. If I just print out the entire Current Item, I'll get the following:

{"id":null,"contentType":"reference","contentUrl":null,"content":null,"name":"Flow Request_2093811450.xlsx","thumbnailUrl":null}.

I need some help splitting the string, so that I'm just getting the name field to print. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Thank you

Comment: If I understand this correctly, Teams attachments are stored in the SharePoint site associated so you will need to get tit from SharePoint.

Comment: Did you ever resolve this? I am having the same problem.